# End-users uploading documents to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

Let's assume that you're the sys admin of 10-30 people company.
You've installed a new SharePoint 2007 server in the organization.
How (which tools, methods) would you have your users upload their documents into SharePoint?
I'm assuming the following:

1. Prior to SharePoint, each user managed his own documents in his "My Documents" or similar folder.
2. Your users are ...ehem... idiots... I mean, new to SharePoint.

Comment: This question is off-topic under current topicality rules.

Answer (score 2):

I would generally get users to use the built in components for uploading files in sharepoint. Uploading a single file is relatively straight forward, uploading multiple files is also quite easy, so long as the user has office 2003 or 2007 installed.

The MSOffice site has a [tutorial page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/HA011412871033.aspx) on uploading files, maybe you can adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Once you create a shared documents folder, the users can go to that folder and use the drop-down under Upload selecting Upload Multiple Documents.  From there they can browse their computer and select any/all documents they want to upload.

Just create step-by step instructions with screen captures and they should be able to do it just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer using "open with window explorer" feature under actions. Lets you drag and drop folders and multiple files. Makes initial setup go faster.

Comment: I would combine this with a logon script that maps a drive letter to this sharepoint resource (I believe this is possible) or put a shortcut to the Sharepoint "explorer view" on their desktop.  We do this for our church and it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say go with the out-of-the-box way of using the Web UI. Either have them create new documents using the new button when viewing the list or by doing a web upload.

Otherwise enable the WebClient service on your end-user's pc's and allow them to drag drop files in either a file share to sharepoint or by opening the Library in Explorer view. By using explorer view / file share you don't have the benefits of "fill in mandatory field first" though. Users can just dump their files in the library without needing to fill in any fields you deem important".